# Data being returned as undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

I am having an issue with JavaScript returning undefined (which is probably more due to my understanding of JS).

I have 2 functions like so:

```js
getData = function(name) {
  var string = "You're name is " + name;
  alert("created string is: " + string); // this alerts "You're name is John"
  return string;
}

firstFunction = function() {
  newString = getData("John");
  alert(newString); // this allerts "undefined"
}

firstFunction();
```

What would be the cause of getData returning undefined to firstFunction?

Comment: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/fpgr5a4f/) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Side note: As shown, the code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) in three places. Be sure to declare your variables. :-)

Comment: Your code is working and I cannot reproduce the issue?

Comment: Your code is working.  Also try declaring newString as you are using it without declaring javascript creates a global variable but if you are using "use strict" then you might get error.

Better to declare and then assign `var newString`

Answer (score 0):

## Code :

```js
<script>
const getData = name => {
    var string = `You're name is ${name}`;
    alert(`created string is: ${string}`); // this alerts "You're name is John"
    // The return string command is not required
}

const firstFunction = () => {
    getData("John");
}

firstFunction();
</script>
```

## Edits :

- Used arrow function instead of normal one
- used string literals instead of normal string
- Possibly fixed the error

## Reading :

- [string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)